# Flash video doesn't show up for unknown reason

Tags: html, flash, browser

I created a flash "intro" (ponicawater.com). On my computer and on my sister's computer it works perfectly, but I receive some messages from people, trying to load the website unsuccessfully. Some of them see a little flash player icon in the top left corner, other see only the first frame, but it's inactive. What could be the reason for this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without knowing more about the structure of your Flash project. One thing for certain is that your page is slow to load. There are two files - ponica.swf at 550KB and bg.jpg at 772KB - which represent a significant download overhead. You could try introducing a preloader to ensure that the .swf file is fully downloaded before it starts to play. You could also put some thought and effort into optimising the images etc. Is it really necessary to load a 773KB JPEG to render circular graduated fill? You could do that far more efficiently using the Flash drawing tools.

Comment: yes, i know it's a bit slow, but this is made on purpose (I mean the separated background from the Flash). Do you see the page working?

Comment: As far as I can see it works (viewed on MacOS 10.6.8, Safari 5.1 and v11.3). It seems to be just a launchpad to four product pages, and the rippling effect under the bottle is very subtle - I didn't notice it at first. It strikes me as very little functionality for a great deal of download overhead. You probably ought to consider providing a non-Flash version as well - at the moment your home page content is inaccessible to the majority of mobile users and search engines.

Answer (score 1):

I see 4 water bottles that move up when you mouse over them.

I think anyone trying to solve this problem needs more details.

What browser & OS did this happen on?  Do they even have a current version of Flash Player installed?
I suspect they may be using an out-of-date Flash Player.

Comment: I have no such details, unfortunately, but the target of the webpage are people around 35-55 years old (traders), who are not really IN the IT, and it's not a surprise they have an old version of Flash player. That's why, it's created with AS2, which is really old. I think, that the problem is with my html, which I would like to post here, so everybody could see it and I will appreciate if you tell me how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to share a large piece of code, you can use pastebin.com and post the link to it here.